# Overriding default umask for docker daemon

Tags: docker, file-permissions

I'm trying to mount a folder on host machine inside a container. In cases when the host folder does not exist, Docker daemon automatically creates the folder on host machine and assigns permissions based on default umask(which is that of root). As a result of this, it is not possible to write to the folder from within the container due to permission issues(script inside container runs as an unprivileged user). I tried overriding the permissions assigned by setting the umask in the startup script for Docker but I believe those are being ignored. Is there any way I can override the umask Docker uses to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I created a script to help with this problem. Here it is:

https://github.com/coppit/docker-inotify-command/blob/master/runas.sh

You call it like:

runas.sh 99 100 0000 /mycommand.sh

99 would be the user ID number, and 100 the group ID number **in the host** that you want to emulate. 0000 is the umask.